# I can not access Count property of the array but through casting to ICollection !

Tags: c#, arrays, icollection

```
        int[] arr = new int[5];
        Console.WriteLine(arr.Count.ToString());//Compiler Error
        Console.WriteLine(((ICollection)arr).Count.ToString());//works print 5
        Console.WriteLine(arr.Length.ToString());//print 5
```

Do you have an explanation for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays have .Length, not .Count.

But this is available (as an **explicit interface implementation**) on ICollection etc.

Essentially, the same as:

```
interface IFoo
{
    int Foo { get; }
}
class Bar : IFoo
{
    public int Value { get { return 12; } }
    int IFoo.Foo { get { return Value; } } // explicit interface implementation
}
```

`Bar` doesn't have public a `Foo` property - but it is available if you cast to `IFoo`:

```
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    Console.WriteLine(bar.Value); // but no Foo
    IFoo foo = bar;
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Foo); // but no Value
```

Answer (score 3):

While `System.Array` implement the `ICollection` interface it doesn't directly expose the `Count` property. You can see the **explicit** implementation of `ICollection.Count` in the MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array_properties.aspx).

The same applies to `IList.Item`.

Take look at this Blog entry for more details on explicit and implicit interface implementation: [Implicit and Explicit Interface Implementations](http://blogs.msdn.com/mhop/archive/2006/12/12/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this doesn't answer your question *directly*, if you are using .NET 3.5 you can include the namespace;

```
using System.Linq;
```

which will then allow you to use a Count() method, similar to when casting your int array as an ICollection.

```
using System.Linq;

int[] arr = new int[5];
int int_count = arr.Count();
```

You also then have a whole host of nice functions you can use in Linq too :)

Comment: .. which would be O(n) instead of O(1)

Comment: @VVS - you are incorrect. Enumerable.Count() checks for ICollection<T>, using .Count internally.