# Counting the number of elements in an Array

Tags: c#, arrays

The `System.Array` class implements `ICollection` interface.
This interface has a public property called `Count` which gives the number of elements in the array.

Suppose I declare an Array and access its properties

```
Array numbers = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 10);
Console.WriteLine(numbers.Count);
```

You would expect to see 10 on the screen.
But, I am not able to see `Count` property after putting a period after numbers. There is however, a property called `Length`. Why is it so?

Update:
This is because of Explicit Interface Implementation. Since there is another question similar to mine, I decided to re-word it.
Why was the design decision taken to explicitly implement this particular property? There is another property with the same functionality `Length`. So why go through the trouble of providing the explicitly implemented `Count`?

Comment: Cast it to `ICollection`.

Comment: Why aren't you using `int[] number = new int[10];` ?

Comment: @PhonicUK, The method I am using is also a valid way of declaring an `Array`. Is there any reason to prefer the syntax you have mentioned?

Comment: @TheSilverBullet It's ok to use `Array.CreateInstance`, but you should not use `Array` type to work with arrays. If you try to access elements of this array, you will get `object` instead of `int32`. This will cause boxing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk(v=vs.80).aspx .Boxing is bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Array` class implements `ICollection` interface explicitly.
You can use methods of `ICollection` only after casting `Array` to `ICollection`

```
Array numbers = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 10);
ICollection numbersCollection =  (ICollection)numbers;
Console.WriteLine(numbersCollection.Count);
```

[Implicit and Explicit Interface Implementations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhop/archive/2006/12/12/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations.aspx)

`System.Array.Count` actually uses `Array.Length` property

```
int ICollection.Count
{
    get
    {
        return this.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you are basically saying that the difference is only in the word used. And this is done to facilitate easier understanding. Essentially a matter of convenience.

Comment: I don't know why it is done this way.

Comment: Ken Kin gives a very acceptable explanation below. Thanks for the answer! I have accepted yours.

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast it to `ICollection`.

[`Array.ICollection.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357392.aspx) Property

> This member is an explicit interface member implementation. It can be
>   used only when the Array instance is cast to an `ICollection`
>   interface.

Btw, here is a duplicate: [I can not access Count property of the array but through casting to ICollection !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031583/i-can-not-access-count-property-of-the-array-but-through-casting-to-icollection)

**Update**:

> This is because of Explicit Interface Implementation. Since there is
>   another question similar to mine, I decided to re-word it. Why was the
>   design decision taken to explicitly implement this particular
>   property? There is another property with the same functionality
>   Length. So why go through the trouble of providing the explicitly
>   implemented Count?

It inherits it from `IList<T>` which implements `ICollection<T>`. So you could ask instead [**why array implements `IList`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968708/why-array-implements-ilist)?.

Comment: "It inherits it from `IList<T>`..." As far as I know `Array` doesn't inherit from `List<T>`. Am I missing something here? And thanks for the link. Learnt something valuable from the discussions there.

Comment: @TheSilverBullet: In C# 2.0 and later, single-dimensional arrays that have a lower bound of zero automatically implement `IList<T>`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228502(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The link you have provided is extremely helpful and it led me to re-read some portion of interface design for list. I would also like to ask why the decision to automatically implement `IList<T>` was taken. But I right now prefer to leave it for another day. I wish I could accept your question as well...

Answer (score 1):

`Count` is implemented explicitly from the `ICollection` interface. That's why it is invisible. You will have to cast `((ICollection) numbers).Count` in order to get access to the `Count` property.

Comment: Thanks, yBee. The thing is once you use the syntax to typecast the array variable, you will not be prompted for any properties. I had to type in `Count` and it worked. Why do you think it is like this?

Comment: @TheSilverBullet: Why `Count` is explicit? Why there is `Length` instead? Programmers are accustomed that when we are speaking about an array, we are speaking about `Length`. But in the other hand, there is an extension method for `IEnumerable` called `Count()` that in fact returns `Length` if operate on array. So probably you should use here `IEnumerable.Count()` instead casting to `ICollection`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not a question of programming, it's a question of logical [intension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intension).

You might ask yourself with these two questions:

**Q1**. Are arrays collections?

**Q2**. Are collections arrays?

In c#, the existing implemention tells that the answer of Q1 is:

**A1**: Yes, arrays are collections. Therefor `Array` implements `ICollection`.

And what about Q2? It's a similar question to ask ***is a horse a white horse***? You might want to take a look of [[When a white horse is not a horse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_a_white_horse_is_not_a_horse)] for the answer.

With Q2, I would reply with: ***"I don't know, it's according to the context."*** 
So, what are the possibly contexts? If you passed an array as an interface implements `ICollection`, then yes, this collection is also an array. However, you might pass a different object except an array with an identical interface. Then, does it necessarily been an array? If you are interested in some extension of this, A3 in [[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965984/what-magic-is-this/14970434#14970434)] might get you the idea.

Thus, **it's totally reasonable**, `Array` has the `Length` property and also has the `Count` property which is from explicit implementation of `ICollection`.

Comment: This answer was helpful in an entirely different way as compared to other answers. The reason behind me questioning the intension is only because I want to dig out some real live design decisions and understand why it was done the way it was done.